# Realtime Stock OHLC Data Bar Plot

Tags: python, highcharts, bar-chart, visualization, stock

I am working on a interesting project where i am receiving realtime data from Broker about the current prices of a stock. I am storing this data in a ohlc dataframe in python ( DateTime as index, open , high , low , close columns ).

I want to visualize this dataframe in barplot like TradingView / AmiBroker.

The Dataframe is dynamic in nature and constantly updating each second. I am unable to update the barplot in realtime.

I have tried various python solutions each of them have a unique kind of issue

1. Plotly : It open's a tab in browser on a link, and shows vis. I want it to open a window like Tkinter does
2. MPL Finance : It updates in realtime but is not horizatally scrollable, it tries to fit all bars in a frame by adjusting their sizes
3. Lightweight Charts : Its window disappears immediately if no new data provided

If any one you has a solution , pls suggest.

Comment: Its seems your requirements might be covered via Highcharts libarry. Have you checked the Highcharts Stock for Python?https://www.highcharts.com/blog/integrations/python/ ;  https://stock-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/demos.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.